# What is the QGD set-up with queen-side fianchetto and c4 called?

Tags: opening

In a recent blitz game, my opponent played a setup that looked like this:

```
[fen "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/2PP4/1P2P3/PB3PPP/RN1QKBNR b - - 0 1"]
```

I can't quite remember where the knights and light-squared bishop went, I guess Nf3, Nd2/c3 and Bd3. I played normal development with d5, e6, Nf6, Nd7, Be7.

Since it was a strong player, I'm assuming this setup or system has a name, but I've unable to find it. Unfortunately I can't recall the move order. What is it called?

Comment: Hard to find the exact name without seeing the moves form Black. This could be a Colle-Zukertort but also some setup against the King's Indian or Grünfeld

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That looks very like the Colle-Zukertort except the c pawn usually doesn't go to c4 quite that early. Normally white develops the kingside pieces and castles first.

Here, for instance is part of Linqvist-Pihlajasalo, Jyvaskyla 1996

```
[Title "Linqvist-Pihlajasalo, Jyvaskyla 1996"]
[fen ""]
[Startply "15"]

1. d4 d5 2.Nf3 Nf6 3. e3 e6 4. Bd3 c5 5. b3 Be7 6. O-O O-O 7. Bb2 b6 8. c4
```

Comment: That looks very familiar. I did look at the Colle-Zukertort in my repertoire book, but missed 8. c4 as it was written as a sideline. Thank you!